# Can someone explain why Trig sub fails but partial fractions is literally the easier method to go about this integral?

Tags: derivatives

so I have this integral:

$$\int\frac{1}{1-v^{2}}dv$$

Now I know this isn't in the form of any of the common integrals for the trig functions, so I decided to use trig sub:

Let $$v = sin(\theta), dv = cos(\theta)$$

After substituting, I end up with $$\int sec(\theta)d\theta$$

which yields $$\ln \bigg|\sec(\theta)+tan(\theta)\bigg |$$

Right? Now if I draw a triangle, since $$\sin(\theta) = \frac{v}{1}$$ then the following substitution is made: $$\ln\bigg|\frac{v+1}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}\bigg |.$$ So I'm not sure how to go from this to this:

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg |\frac{v+1}{v-1}\bigg |$$

I tried solving this integral using Partial Fractions and it was very easy to get to this form, but I'm not sure where to go about with the answer I arrived at. Some help would be appreciated.

*Also, please ignore the fact that I did not add a + C, this is just the LHS of a differential equation I am trying to solve.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just note that $$\frac{v+1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} = \frac{v+1}{\sqrt{1+v}\sqrt{1-v}} = \frac{\sqrt{1+v}}{\sqrt{1-v}}$$

So the two are infact equivalent under appropriate domain.

Comment: Right, well I did it a different way. I squared both sides and I got (v+1)^2 over 1-v^2, then the final result ends up as 1+v over 1-v, but it's still not the same as theirs? Because they have v+1 over v-1

Comment: @stuy if you are anyway putting a modulus sign $|x|$ then you always have $|-x| = |x|$